# Intercept input property changes with a setter ang getter in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I started learning Angular, and I ran into this code from the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter):

`NameChildComponent`:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-child',
  template: '<h3>"{{name}}"</h3>'
})
export class NameChildComponent {
  @Input()
  get name(): string { return this._name; }
  set name(name: string) {
    this._name = (name && name.trim()) || '<no name set>';
  }
  private _name = '';
}
```

`NameParentComponent`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-parent',
  template: `
    <h2>Master controls {{names.length}} names</h2>

    <app-name-child *ngFor="let name of names" [name]="name"></app-name-child>
  `
})
export class NameParentComponent {
  // Displays 'Dr IQ', '<no name set>', 'Bombasto'
  names = ['Dr IQ', '   ', '  Bombasto  '];
}
```

So, as far as I understand, when the `NameChildComponent` is rendered:

1. `set name()` is invoked first .
2. The template is using `get name()` to get the name to be rendered in the template.

Now, I tried deleting `get name()` method, and I expected to get an error because there is no way for a template to get the `name`. However, there is no error, and instead  I get :

```
""
""
""
```

I probably don't understand how all this works together, and I'd appreciate if someone could tell me if my assumptions are correct,  and why  I don't get an error if I delete the getter. Thank you.

Comment: it should be just undefined, if the getter is not defined. just a simple js property which is not declared. when you render undefined value in angular template you see an empty string

Comment: @Andrei Thanks, however, shouldn't it throw an error in this case?

Comment: no, it is expected to render empty strings in place of undefineds. but if you try to call some method of a string on it, then it will throw. for example `{{name.trim()}}`.